# Send mail from Gmail smtp via python fail when authenticate

Tags: python, gmail

I try to send mail from gmail smtp, but many libs i use fail with same issues, so i write code my own, but still got same issues.

The mail address and password are correct, and set "Allow applications that are not secure enough: Enabled
", but still fail when login.

```
In [3]: import smtplib

In [4]: sender = "xxxx@gmail.com"

In [5]: receiver = ["a@m.com", "b@m.com"]

In [6]: message = "Some say, the hole that you have is not what you think about. "

In [7]: session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

In [8]: session.ehlo()
Out[8]:
(250,
 'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [52.69.222.223]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')

In [9]: session.starttls()
Out[9]: (220, '2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')

In [10]: session.ehlo()
Out[10]:
(250,
 'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [52.69.222.223]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')

In [11]: session.login(sender,'xxxxxxxxxx')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMTPAuthenticationError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d9e3f09f8956> in <module>()
----> 1 session.login(sender,'RVt-p2o-DNH-KUx')

/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in login(self, user, password)
    620             # 235 == 'Authentication successful'
    621             # 503 == 'Error: already authenticated'
--> 622             raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
    623         return (code, resp)
    624

SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsM\n5.7.14 0ac0_dvD0Y_cg29gAxTuOXREOWblLYFSrQlrVnGUA98X18_Bht8wEh-uL_nhqDReDOqF8Z\n5.7.14 Ll39ZurQoK631iZ9Q_cbkAAHqRZBpWMfGnZUMUONSycVww2_YydzB0vQUGGb3lrboeriGh\n5.7.14 gHVI6Vw5SUYyUDCJyfV3Jav_oJFgbLvyK2a0UwllJvt8gQqvy7JhpFIQoybHlpuG5ZLu23\n5.7.14 JNo4Ru7q6vU3aaRfWKl7YoNnRRVHA> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 s14sm19463632pfe.36 - gsmtp')
```